# Borderless RippleDrawable issue when notifying RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm having a horizontal `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass with a simple `LinearLayout` row, having `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` as a background:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
          android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

An interface for the view's `OnClickListener` is set from the `RecyclerView` - nothing fancy here.

The OnClickListener is handling the "selected" color of the view, and passing some data to another interface:

```
setAdapter(new CalendarViewAdapter(view -> {
        int position = getChildLayoutPosition(view);
        if (position == selectedDayPosition) return;

        getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(selectedDayPosition);
        selectedDayPosition = position;
        getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(selectedDayPosition);

        //view.setPressed(true);  
        //view.setPressed(false); <-- That didn't help as well (nor delaying in a handler etc.)

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onDayPicked(CalendarPicker.this.days.get(selectedDayPosition).getPaginationInfo());
        }
    }));
```

My concern is after the `notifyItemChanged()` instead of the nice fade out of the ripple I end up with this weird result:

[image]
*screenshot taken in the moment of the release of the touch event*

My only explanation is this is some strange combination between the `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` and `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. But I want it only in the borderless style.

There are a few questions on this subject, I tried all of the answers but unfortunately they are all using `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and not the borderless variation.

Any help with my UI dilemma will be highly appreciated!